# How to wait till nested forkjoin is finished?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

i have a problem with a nested forkjoin, when i try to subscribe pull, it's getting back my data, but i can see that getitem3 is still running. How to wait till all functions are finished before subscribe

see example

```
pull(id) {
  return Observable.forkJoin(
    this.getitem1(id),
    this.getitem2(id),
    this.getitem3(id)
  );
}



getitem3(id) {
  let url = 'https://host3/get/' + id;
  let observableBatch = [];

  return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).map(data => {
    data.posts.data.forEach((item) => {
      observableBatch.push(this.getImageUrl(item.id));
    })
    return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch);
  })
}


getitem2(id) {
  let url = 'https://host2/get/' + id;
  let observableBatch = [];

  return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).map(data => {
   data.posts.data.forEach((item) => {
     observableBatch.push(this.getImageUrl(item.id));
   });
   return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch);

  });
}

 getitem1(id) {
  let url = 'https://host1/get/' + id;
  let observableBatch = [];

  return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).map(data => {
    data.posts.data.forEach((item) => {
      observableBatch.push(this.getImageUrl(item.id));
    });
    return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch);
  });
}

getImageUrl(id) {
  let url = 'https://localhost/image/' + id;
  return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).map(data => {
    console.log('done');
  });
}
```

Comment: Inside your `getImageUrl(id)` method, you are using `subscribe`, hence it is calling the url. Remove the `subscribe` (so it will return an observable) and try again.

Comment: I changed subscribe to map. do i have to subscribe it in my getItem then?

Comment: No you should subscribe to `pull(id)` method if that's the only one you need.

Answer (score 3):

I think your methods  `getitemN()` returns `Observable <Observable<any>>`. And when you subscribing you just calling first observable, to call anothers you can use `flatMap` instead of `map`.

```
.flatMap(data => {
                data
                    .posts
                    .data
                    .forEach((item) => {
                        observableBatch.push(this.getImageUrl(item.id));
                    })
                return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch);
            })
```

So in this case you will get only `Observable <any>`.

Here is also helpful information: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-and-http. FlatMap is in "Dependent calls" section.

Comment: I can't add comment to main question.
.map(data => {            console.log('done');       }). Here you do not return the data so, at subscriber you get nothing. If you want write code with some side effects like log to console you can use do() method. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/do.md

Comment: Thanks man, that is exactly what i needed. It's working as expected now.